# Performing the math behind public key cryptography

Tags: java, math, public-key-encryption

I was pretty fascinated by [this simple example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QnD2c4Xovk) of the idea behind public key cryptography, and sat down to write my own `Client <- Server -> Client` example using Java. Just a simple back and forth that encodes messages using the resulting secret.

The problem I initially encountered was a *technical* one. In the demonstration, the author determines the result of the equation:

`3 ^ (24 * 54) mod 17`

With a value:

`= 1`

**But my question is, how would one approach the calculation of such a large number in Java?**

Or is the example provided simply that: *an example*, and not the actual method of calculation?

Comment: Modular exponentiation by repeated squaring. If nobody elaborated until I return from dinner, I will.

Comment: Wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be a good mathematical reason for it (Daniel Fischer seems to have one). In any case, you can use a BigInteger:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("3")
          .modPow(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(24 * 54)), new BigInteger("17"));
    System.out.println(bi);
}
```

which outputs 1.

Comment: Interesting! I also found the `valueOf()` static method - it seems to be slightly easier to use: `BigInteger.valueOf(3).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(24 * 54), BigInteger.valueOf(17))`

Comment: Emphasis on `slightly` easier. Heavy objects are heavy. :(

Comment: For the life of me I still don't know why there isn't a BigInteger constructor capable of taking a numeric literal.

Comment: @Wug Yes - I wonder every time I need to use that class too ;-)

Comment: @Wug I believe it's intentionally missing to facilitate internal caching/reuse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class to deal with such big numbers. It provides arithmetic operations on big integers.